# Soil wetting compounds: are they effective?

Tags: grass, dryness, lawn

Crystals, sprays, etc. Are soil wetting products effective to rejuvenate dry sections in a lawn? Any recommendations?

Comment: If this is the area of lawn mentioned in your other question, just water it often - its dry because its in rainshadow, meaning the rain doesn't get on it because of the overhanging eaves and the house wall.

Answer (score 4):

This is something I looked into a while ago and wrote about it on my site discussing [if liquid aeration works](http://www.organiclawndiy.com/2009/05/does-liquid-aeration-work.html).

Based on my own use of surfactants and the research I came across I haven't found them to be effective for lawns contrary to what some people on forums indicate. They soil would have to be very dry and hydrophobic where it can't absorb any water for them to be effective. This is not a common situation in lawns.

If you have dry spots in your lawn adding organic matter to the area like  good compost, core aerating and making sure your sprinklers are set up properly to provide good coverage. Sometimes people mistake other problems for dry spots.

Surfactants do have benefits when used in conjunction with other treatments as the surfactant can aid in the transport and stickiness of the applied treatment but for dealing with dry spots, not in my experience and reading.

Comment: aeration and decomposed mulches make a huge difference...these chemicals and wetting gels are bulloney...don't just wet the surface, soak the soil and allow to dry out before soaking again.

Comment: I have also read that these products can wash into rivers and water tables to no good effect.